# integer roots of a quadratic equation

Tags: number-theory

Can you prove that the equation, $3x^2+3xr+r^2-d^3=0$ has an integer positive solution only if $\gcd(d,r)\neq 1$, where $x,d,r$ are all positive integers and $x > r$?

**My approach**: I tried using Quadratic equation root formula,
$$x= \frac{-3r+ \sqrt{12d^3-3r^2}}{6}$$ I also used integer root theorem, as per which $x$ must be a factor of $(d^3-r^2)$ and tried to divide $(d^3-r^2)$ by the algebraic expression of $x$. But it doesn't lead to any conclusion.

Comment: you don't need any extra condition? If $d$ is small and $r$ big we have that the polynomial has no real solutions.

Comment: @Marcos good point, I guess one must read "$d > r$" instead of "$x > r$.

Comment: All such similar equations always have solutions.  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1054060

Comment: d3 is greater than r2, that's obvious.

Comment: @MridulDey explicit is better than implicit, especially in maths.

Comment: @Mridul Dey: Please identify the source of the problem. If it's from a book, which one (author, title, page #, prob #)? . If it's from a contest, which one (contest name, date, prob #)?

Comment: @individ: The OP's question is whether a solution exists with $\gcd(d,r)=1$. The formulas you reference shed no light on that.

Comment: I have given these formulas as an example. Usually they can be extremely cumbersome and will not be mutually simple explicitly. After that, it is often necessary to reduce by a common divisor. In some cases there will be mutually simple solutions, and in others there will not. Therefore, the question itself does not make sense. Because it is unlikely that a very cumbersome formula will be useful to him.

Comment: @quasi Here is another example of such equations. Some of the solutions are mutually simple. Part no. With such a formula, will it be possible to separate some solutions from others?  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1057357_diophantine_equation_with_cubes

Comment: @MridulDey Please do not change the question, especially after answers have been posted. Rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

The claim is false.

In fact, there are infinitely many counterexamples.

For one such example, you can use $(x,r,d)=(90,19,31)$.

As regards your query regarding the case where $r$ is a perfect cube . . .

**Claim:**$\;$There do not exist positive rational numbers $x,r,d$ such that
$$
3x^2+3xr+r^2-d^3=0
$$
and such that $r$ is the cube of a rational number.

**Proof:**

Suppose otherwise.

Let $r=s^3$ for some positive rational number $s$.

Let $b,c$ be defined by
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
b=\frac{x}{s^3}\\[4pt]
c=\frac{d}{s^2}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
and let $a=b+1$.

Then $a,b,c$ are positive rational numbers and we have
\begin{align*}
&
3x^2+3xr+r^2-d^3=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
3x^2+3xr+r^2=d^3
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
3x^2+3xs^3+s^6=d^3
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
3(s^3b)^2+3(s^3b)s^3+s^6=(s^2c)^3
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
s^6(3b^2+3b+1)=s^6c^3
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
3b^2+3b+1=c^3
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(b+1)^3-b^3=c^3
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a^3-b^3=c^3
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which is impossible (this is the $n=3$ case of Fermat's Last Theorem).

Comment: Thank you. It works.

Comment: There is another condition to this problem that 'r' is a positive cubic no, say r = l^3. Is there any counterexample then?

Comment: @Mridul Dey: You never answered the question I asked in the main comments. Where does the problem come from? What does it relate to?

Comment: It's not from any book. I was checking the properties of cubic numbers. kindly check if you can find any counterexample for r = l^3. Thanks.

Comment: @Mridul Dey: If $r$ is assumed to be a perfect cube, a counterexample does not exist.

Comment: Thanks. How did you get to that conclusion?

Comment: Fermat's Last theorem is applicable for integers. Here, a, b, c is needed to be shown as integers.

Comment: @Mridul Dey: Fermat's Last Theorem is valid for nonzero rationals. Explicitly, if we assume $a,b,c$ are nonzero rationals such that 
$$a^3-b^3=c^3$$
then if we write $a,b,c$ using a common denominator as
$$
a=\frac{A}{D},
\;\;\;
b=\frac{B}{D},
\;\;\;
c=\frac{C}{D}
$$
where $A,B,C,D$ are nonzero integers, it follows that
$$
A^3-B^3=C^3
$$
contradiction.

Comment: Like you said, for Fermat's theorem to be valid for rational numbers a,b,c should have same denominator. But in our problem, the denominator is not same, for b it is s^3 but for c it is s^2.

Comment: @Mridul Dey: Any finite sequence of rational numbers can be rewritten using a common denominator.